# How to change the beginning form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I need help with a windows form. I created several windows forms and i am trying to link them together. right now **form4** has got two buttons that I want to link to **form2** and **form3**. My first button on **form4** doesn't load the **form2** it just reloads itself when i click the button. the code I have for the button is:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }
```

on the **form2** I have a load event

```
  private void form4_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f4 = new Form4();
        this.Close();
        f4.ShowDialog();

    }
```

this is what button1_click looks like on form2:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.setPlayerNames(p1.Text, p2.Text);
        this.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to reproduce the problem.  Presumably your second form is doing something that prevents it from being shown.

Comment: i want form4 to be my start form, and want it to link to form2 and form3

Comment: if you want to change the start form go to program.cs and change it to this. Application.Run(new Form4())

Comment: Ok, i did that. The button on form 4 that links to form2 still dosn't work

Comment: From the code you posted, it seems you are trying to open Form4 from the same Form4's Load Event ?

Comment: ok i deleted the load event on form2 and it works

Comment: To be honest i'm not quite knowledgeable about load events. Should I remove one of the load events or even both of them? cause on my form2 I have two load events. one for form2, and one for form4

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems. First one is how modal form works, you will have to do it like this:

```
void form4_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f4 = new Form4();
    this.Close(); // close first
    f4.ShowDialog();
}
```

otherwise `this.Close` doesn't happens until you close `f4`.

Second is related to how starting form is running. Typically you have code

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

you must change it to something like

```
var f1 = new Form1();
f1.ShowDialog();
```

otherwise when you close `f1` your application will terminate. And you don't want this, you want another form to act as main form.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong the button on form 2 wont load form 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the form on the program.cs, like this:

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form4());
    }
}
```

And leave the load event on form2 empty, like this;

```
private void form4_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

You have already loaded the form4 on the start, no need to load it again

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you are trying to do, but this is what happens:

By pressing the button you are creating a form of the type Form2.

When Form2 finishes loading it creates a new form of the type Form4 and shows it.

So basicly what happens:

---

**Form4** is created.

User pressed **Button1** on **Form4**.

**Button1** creates new **Form2** and shows it.

**Form2** loads, creates a new **Form4** and shows it.

---

This is why you see Form4 "reloads" itself.

If you delete the line showing Form4 in Form2 load event, you will see the Form2 being created.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Hide();
     new Form2().Show();
}
```

shorter way, remove `Hide();` if you don't want form1 to hide.